# Can one trigger ng-class after ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following element:

```
<a href="" ng-click="project.hasPhotos? removeFromProject(project, $index, currentPhoto) : addToProject($index, currentPhoto)" ng-class="{'selected-project': (belongsPhotoToProject(project, $index, currentPhoto) || project.hasPhotos)}">{{ project.label }}</a>
```

The idea of the `ng-class` is this: if the photo belongs to the project, the function `belongsPhotoToProject` returns `true`, so the `selected-project` class is set. Now, on click, after the function `removeFromProject(project, $index, currentPhoto)` is triggered, `belongsPhotoToProject` does not evaluate to `true` anymore, so I expect it to remove the class, however, this doesn't happen.

So my questions are: after the initial page load, on which page events does `ng-click` get triggered? If `ng-click` gets triggered only on page load, can I manually trigger it again on `ng-click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work as you described it.  Here's a plnkr showing it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/V4R0EUwKK5TeH5wn7Y5N?p=preview

Are you getting any errors in your browser?

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.project = {
    hasPhotos: true,
    label: "My Test Project"
  };

  $scope.removeFromProject = function(project, $index, currentPhoto) {
    $scope.project.hasPhotos = false;
  };

  $scope.addToProject = function($index, currentPhoto) {
    $scope.project.hasPhotos = true;
  };

  $scope.belongsPhotoToProject = function(project, $index, currentPhoto) {
    return $scope.project.hasPhotos;
  };

});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <a href="" ng-click="project.hasPhotos? removeFromProject(project, $index, currentPhoto) : addToProject($index, currentPhoto)" ng-class="{'selected-project': (belongsPhotoToProject(project, $index, currentPhoto) || project.hasPhotos)}">{{ project.label }}</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
.selected-project {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```